# Workbook parameter based on application version

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks

I created a custom workbook like this

```
AppInventory_CL
| where AppName_s in ('Adobe Acrobat Reader DC') or '*' in ('Adobe Acrobat Reader DC')
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s
| extend Versione = iif(AppVersion_s == '15.007.20033','OK','KO')
```

So, if the acrobat reader version is 15.007.20033 the AppVersion_s writes OK otherwise writes KO....everything works

I'd like to create a dropdown menu to show all the "OK" devices or the "KO" ones
How can I achieve this?

I'd like to create a dropdown menu to show all the "OK" devices or the "KO" ones

Answer (score -1):

You could create a muliselect dropdown using the JSON data source with values
["KO", "OK"], (and i made it multiselect, with all as an option by default)

[image: parameter settings]

produces this dropdown

[image: dropdown]

then you could use it like:

```
let include = dynamic([{Switch}]);
AppInventory_CL
| where AppName_s in ('Adobe Acrobat Reader DC') or '*' in ('Adobe Acrobat Reader DC')
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s
| extend Versione = iif(AppVersion_s == '15.007.20033','OK','KO')
// new filters start here
| where array_length(include) == 0  // nothing selected = all
  or "*" in (include) // special case all selected = all
  or Versione in (include) // or the exact value in selection
```

- if nothing is selected in the dropdown, it shows all items
- if all is selected in the dropdown it shows all items
- if any item is selected it includes that item

(i don't have your exact data, so i can't verify the query directly but that should work?)